# The complete circuit of this project

Tags: pcb-design, altium, solar-charge-controller

This circuit is a solar charge controller module Can you help me get the schematic and PCB of this circuit?

[image]

Comment: Please explain in details what is really your problem here. Do you want to make this PCB yourself (and why) or do you look for a place where you can buy it?

Comment: At first i need details of this circuit and then make PCB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 8 pin IC and a 10 pin IC. You need to know what they do. I guess the 8 pin IC is a linear voltage regulator and the 10 pins IC is a battery charging monitor IC.

If it's exact, search for these two component on the internet (on on-line vendor websites). Download the datasheets. Inside these datasheets you will see explanations on how to replicate this circuit, schematic samples, informations about the other components and maybe hints on how to improve it.

If it's not exact, then search only for a battery charging monitor IC.

Comment: I did all these steps Unfortunately, I could not find the schematic of this circuit and even the chip number I only know that it is a mppt solar charge controller

Comment: You don't have to find the chip number and there is little chance that you will find it. You have to find a similar chip with the battery charging monitor function (DC-DC or "solar panel" in the keywords). Then reconstruct a new schematic. If you don't know in advance which chip it is exactly it's very difficult to reverse engineer a circuit. Searching the exact chip will take you more time than redesigning the entire circuit yourself. This picture can only gives you some inspiration on how it should look like.

Comment: If you find chips with the same number of pins, it's possible that it's the same but not guaranteed.